# How do I add a comment from a file in zip?

Tags: file, zip

I'm making a script that compresses a directory to a ZIP archive. I want to add a comment that I put in a file to the archive.

Said comment has already been loaded on the script, so how do I get that loaded comment into my zip file without user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

Use `zipnote` command. Here you can find [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zipnote).

```
zipnote -w foo.zip < file_with_comments
```